# How to create plain text representations of tables in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, plaintext

I will give a little background.  I'm working on a pay-per-click engine, and I am running into a problem generating reports (daily, weekly, monthly) that contain a user's listings and clicks with a rate / total column.  I want to represent this information in plain-text format for compatibility reasons, and also because I hate HTML mail.

Should I try to do this?  Or just send them a notification that their invoice / summary is available in the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in case you prefer not to reinvent the wheel, there's pear [console_table](http://pear.php.net/package/Console_Table) or a tiny but working function of mine http://stereofrog.com/blok/on/070116.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the lists of data and use the sprintf function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to display each line while maintaining consistent spacing.

You can similarly accomplish maintaining constitent spacing with the str_pad function (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

Comment: Thanks. Once I figure out how to use it, I believe it will do exactly what I need!